# jquery picture viewer

Tags: jquery, html

So I am trying to make a part of my site have a picture and I have arrows on either side that change the photo in the center.

```
<div id="main_photo">
            <div id="main_photo_1">
            <img id="main_photo_img" src="images/main_photo2.jpg" alt="photo" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="left_arrow"><a href=""><img id="left_arrow_image" src="images/arrow_left.jpg" alt="Navigate images left" /></a></div>
        <div id="right_arrow"><a href=""><img id="right_arrow_image" src="images/arrow_right.jpg" alt="Navigate images right" /></a></div>
```

It changes the picture but only for half a second then the original image comes back.  As a side question how can I make it so that it changes the img src in increments.  like main_photo_(# to increment).jpg

```
$('#left_arrow').click(function() {
        $('#main_photo_img').attr('src', "images/main_photo3.jpg");
    });
```

Comment: How can you have a side question when you don't have a main question?

Answer (score 0):

the original image comes back because you don't stop the link from reloading the page.
so the jQuery changes the image but then the #left_arrow links to its href ("") which is the same page.

you'll have to stop the click event like so:

```
$('#left_arrow').click(function(ev) {
    $('#main_photo_img').attr('src', "images/main_photo3.jpg");
    ev.preventDefault();
});
```

---

if you want to increment the image on each click:

```
var counter = 0;
var imageCount = 4;
$('#left_arrow').click(function(ev) {
    if(++counter>imageCount) counter = 1;
    $('#main_photo_img').attr('src', "images/main_photo"+counter+".jpg");
    ev.preventDefault();
});
```

this should increment the counter up to your image count and then start at 1

Comment: works too, but i tend to use preventDefault(). (they don't do exactly the same though)